# Error 400 Bad Request while creating *.DAT file in Document Library CSOM C# (2010)

Tags: 2010, development, document-library, csom

I am having file binary data and I want to create File with this blob data into SharePoint 2010.

I am using CSOM(C#) to interact with SharePoint 2010.

I am able to create all the files successfully with the help of following code:

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
    List documentLibrary = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(documentLibraryName);

    FileCreationInformation fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation();
    fileCreationInformation.Content = fileContent;
    fileCreationInformation.Overwrite = true;
    fileCreationInformation.Url = "Url of File";
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = documentLibrary.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInformation);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

But when I am creating **`*.DAT`** file, it gives me error

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

This file extension is already allowed from `Central Administration`. While I am uploading the **`*.DAT`** file from browser its uploading successfully.

So can any one figure out why it is giving "**The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.**" through code?

Any Help would be appreciable.